# Makefile - move object files

Tags: makefile

After a bit of searching, I've managed to throw together the following Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
LDFLAGS = 
SOURCEFILES = main.c
SOURCES = src/$(SOURCEFILES)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE = netsim

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf netsim $(OBJECTS)
```

I would like to be able to move my object files into another directory, but have been struggling with getting that to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean build them elsewhere, or move them after they're built, as part of the `.c.o` rule, or what?

Comment: Build them elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to not move your objects.
You should *build it* and *use it from where they are built*.

For example you have the following directory structure:

```
$ tree .
├── Makefile
├── include
│   └── common_head.h
├── obj
└── src
    ├── foo.c
    └── main.c
```

Manual execution:

```
$ gcc -o ./obj/foo.o  -c ./src/foo.c  -I ./include  # Build Object #
$ gcc -o ./obj/main.o -c ./src/main.c -I ./include
$ gcc -o exe ./obj/foo.o ./obj/main.o               # Build Executable #
```

---

Makefile to simulate the above

```
C_FLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra
CC := gcc
RM := rm
LINKFLAGS := -lanylibrary

.PHONY: $(TARGET)
.PHONY: clean

VPATH:= ./src/ ./obj/ ./include/

# Path for .c , .h and .o Files 
SRC_PATH := ./src/
OBJ_PATH := ./obj/
INC_PATH := -I ./include

# Executable Name 
TARGET := exe

# Files to compile
OBJ1 := foo.o \
        main.o

OBJ := $(patsubst %,$(OBJ_PATH)%,$(OBJ1))

# Build .o first
$(OBJ_PATH)%.o: $(SRC_PATH)%.c
                @echo [CC] $<
                @$(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(INC_PATH)                  

# Build final Binary
$(TARGET):      $(OBJ)
                @echo [INFO] Creating Binary Executable [$(TARGET)]
                @$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LINKFLAGS)

# Clean all the object files and the binary
clean:   
                @echo "[Cleaning]"
                @$(RM) -rfv $(OBJ_PATH)*
                @$(RM) -rfv $(TARGET)
```

---

So when you do a Make

```
$ make -B
[CC] src/foo.c
[CC] src/main.c
[INFO] Creating Binary Executable [exe]
```

To see a dry-run use `make -n`

```
$ make clean ; make -n
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -o obj/foo.o  -c src/foo.c  -I ./include
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -o obj/main.o -c src/main.c -I ./include
g++ -o  exe  obj/foo.o obj/main.o -lanylibrary
```

---

So after building your directory structure should look like this.

```
$ tree .
├── Makefile
├── exe
├── include
│   └── common_head.h
├── obj
│   ├── foo.o
│   └── main.o
└── src
    ├── foo.c
    └── main.c
```

So from my previous answer.
You don't have to use any `PHONY move` and also no objects are recreated unnecessarily.

Comment: Doesn't moving the object files afterwards defeat the purpose of keeping them around in the first place? If the executable is built prior to moving them, then I would think that each time make is run, all object files would have to be recreated in order to generate a new executable. I was hoping to put object files in a separate directory prior to generating the executable so that unchanged files could be reused.

Comment: This is not a good makefile.  Declaring all the objects to depend on all the sources means any time you change any source file, all the object files will rebuild.  In your example you have only one source file so it makes no difference but presumably a real makefile will have more source.

Comment: @MadScientist & kubiej21 Answer updated.  Makefile rewritten. The above Makefile should solve the issues. I am coming back to this question after almost a year !

Comment: @SaurabhMeshram what is the use of `VPATH:= ./src/ ./obj/ ./include/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SOURCES = src/main.c
OBJECTS = obj/main.o

...

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Once that's working, you can add further tricks, like this:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst src/%.c, obj/%.o, $(SOURCES)
```

Comment: Actually the recipe part is probably unnecessary -- GNU Make already knows how to compile `.c` into `.o` -- but the dependency relation obviously needs to be declared.

Comment: @tripleee while it's true that make knows how to compile a `.c` into a `.o`, it _does not_ know how to compile a `src/...c` into an `obj/...o`.  So, a pattern rule is needed.