# Makefile - a command in a command?

Tags: makefile

I have an embarrassingly simple makefile question but I can't google it due to lack of knowledge - I don't know the words for things I don't know.

Basically, I want to run the makefile in the current directory, look into the ./SRC directory for source files and when everything is finished, move the object files into the ./OBJ directory.

Makefile:

```
move_obj: 
    mv -f -t ./OBJ_DIR ./$(OBJ_FILES)

file.o: other_file.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c file.c
    move_obj
```

I want to call "move_obj" after compiling the source files but since I don't know what

```
result: dependency
    evaluation
```

*actually* represents (and all makefile introduction guides I've found state "This is what a makefile looks like, off you go then"), I don't know why this isn't working. I assume I need some evaluate command or need to define a function or...?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: can do this by putting a dependency on file.o in move_obj..

Comment: Why not output the objects to the `obj` folder in the first place, rather than building them somewhere else then moving them?

Comment: Unless you are using **make file.o**, make works from the first colon.  If you just type **make**, it will try to run **move_obj**.  To fix, move the file,o block above the move_obj block

Comment: Hi, yeah, that's what I'm doing. The user has to specify the target (make file.o was just a simplification). But it's good to know that make will run everything if you just type "make".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating another `rule` for example `move`, like below

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE) move

$(EXECUTABLE):  $(OBJECTFILES)
            $(CC) -o $@ $<
$(OBJECTFILES): $(SOURCEFILES)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ -I $(INCLUDE_PATH) $<

# Move the .o to Object directory #
move:           
            $(MV) $(OBJECTFILES) $(OBJECT_PATH)
```

---

But by doing the above, you will **defeat the purpose of the Makefile**.
Since your rule is dependent on `.o`, `Make` will look for `.o` in current directory and not find it (because you've moved it) and thus rebuild.

To avoid this, you should output it to `./obj` directory and use it from there.
Something like

```
gcc -g -Wall -o obj/foo.o  -c src/foo.c  -I ./include
gcc -g -Wall -o obj/main.o -c src/main.c -I ./include
gcc -o  exe  obj/foo.o obj/main.o -lanylibrary
```

Below is the makefile doing the same.

```
C_FLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra
CC := gcc
RM := rm
LINKFLAGS := -lanylibrary

.PHONY: $(TARGET) clean

VPATH:= ./src/ ./obj/ ./include/

# Path for .c , .h and .o Files 
SRC_PATH := ./src/
OBJ_PATH := ./obj/
INC_PATH := -I ./include

# Executable Name 
TARGET := exe

# Files to compile
OBJ1 := foo.o \
        main.o

OBJ := $(patsubst %,$(OBJ_PATH)%,$(OBJ1))

# Build .o first
$(OBJ_PATH)%.o: $(SRC_PATH)%.c
                @echo [CC] $<
                @$(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(INC_PATH)                  

# Build final Binary
$(TARGET):      $(OBJ)
                @echo [INFO] Creating Binary Executable [$(TARGET)]
                @$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LINKFLAGS)

# Clean all the object files and the binary
clean:   
                @echo "[Cleaning]"
                @$(RM) -rfv $(OBJ_PATH)*
                @$(RM) -rfv $(TARGET)
```

---

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26032630/2968959) for a better understanding

**EDIT**:
You can also output your executable to directory, add the following changes to your `Makefile`.
Ensure that the `bin` directory is created beforehand, and not deleted by `clean`.

```
# Path for .c , .h and .o Files, and ./bin directory
BIN_PATH := ./bin

# Executable Name 
TARGET := $(BIN_PATH)/exe

# Clean all the object files and the binary
clean:   
                @echo "[Cleaning]"
                @$(RM) -rfv $(OBJ_PATH)*
                @$(RM) -fv $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. You answered the question I asked and also the one I hadn't, but should of, since it gives the correct answer. By the same logic, I assume I want to link everything in the /bin/ directory?

Comment: I didn't want to create another question since this is the same topic but I'm having trouble redirecting the output from a list of source files. 

SRC_FILES = file1.c file2.c file3.c.....

$(CC) -c $(SRC_FILES) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@

file1.o: file1.c 
    gcc ....
file2.o: file2.c
    gcc ...

Essentially, I want to create a library by compiling a list of sources files in /src/, have the list of object files in /obj/, then link them to create libmine.a/libmine.dll.  For the code above, I get 

fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files, which I understand but can't fix..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a target(`move_obj`) after another(file.o), add the `move_obj` to the dependency list of `file.o` so that the commands under the `move_obj`  will be executed.

So your `Makefile` should be:

```
file.o: other_file.h move_obj
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c file.c

move_obj: 
    mv -f -t ./OBJ_DIR ./$(OBJ_FILES)
```

As `Colonel Thirty Two` mentioned in the comment section, instead of compiling and then move, you can build the object files in the required directory

```
file.o: other_file.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c file.c -o ./$(OBJ_FILES)/$@
```

Comment: Really good answer, thank you. I gave the accepted solution to Saurabh since he also gave me the code for the "bad answer" (though I may use it for something else later) and his was a bit more comprehensive, explaining the reasoning behind not wanting to move object files. But your answer answered my question perfectly as well so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is flawed in various ways.

1. `result` normally is an actual file that should be present after the recipe is executed. If the file is already there and is not older than any of its dependencies, `make` does nothing. So instead of creating a file somewhere and then moving it around with another rule, make sure the rule creates it where it should FINALLY be. Otherwise `make` can never check whether it has to rebuild it (and always will). In this case, use the `-o` flag of the compiler to directly create it where it should be (e.g. `-o $(OBJ_DIR)/file.o`)
2. `dependency` should list ALL files that are needed to build the `result`, so `make` really rebuilds it if ANY of these files changed. In your case, at least `file.c` is missing from the dependency list
3. In order to place files in a directory, you should make sure it exists. you could do it like this:

   ```
   $(OBJ_DIR):
       mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

   $(OBJ_DIR)/file.o: $(OBJ_DIR) file.c other_file.h
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c file.c -o $(OBJ_DIR)/file.o
   ```
4. Your move_obj recipe, although not suitable in this case, would be a `PHONY` target, meaning it does not create a file. If you need such rules, mark them accordingly by mentioning them as dependency of the special target `.PHONY`:

   ```
   .PHONY: move_obj
   ```

   The reason for this is that you could (by accident) have a file named move_obj in your working directory. In that case, make would decide there's nothing to do for move_obj, and this is not what you want. Marking it as phony tells make that this rule does not create its target and the recipe must be executed no matter what.

All in all, your question comes down to misunderstanding a Makefile as kind of a script. It is not. It's a declarative file that tells make what has to be done in order to build files (your `evaluation` block) and when this needs to be done (your `dependency` block). It's better not to try to misuse a Makefile as a script.

Comment: Thanks Felix for the comments. file.c was missing since I just chopped up the makefile I'm editing and it wasn't needed to illustrate my problem. But I hear what you're saying. You're right, I do tend to think of makefiles as scripts since I use them fairly infrequently to accomplish a particular goal. It seems best I just sit down and learn them once and for all to avoid these kinds of problems in future.