# Makefile: compile objects to different directory and build from there

Tags: c++, makefile, subdirectory

My Makefile:

```
CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++14
LDFLAGS = -lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl -lcpprest -lpthread

OBJDIR = obj
SRCDIR = .

SRC := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name "*.cpp")
OBJ := $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

APP = run

all: $(APP)

$(APP): $(OBJ)
    @echo "== LINKING EXECUTABLE $(APP)"
    @$(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $(APP)

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "COMPILING SOURCE $< INTO OBJECT $@"
    @$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    find . -name *.o -delete
    rm -f $(APP)
```

Directory structure:

```
Makefile
sources/
    directory1
        ...cpp
    directory2
        ...cpp
    ...
    main.cpp
obj/
```

I try to make `make` create `*.o` files in a directory `obj/` and then compile the final executable from there. I tried various approaches and they fail because of the project structure that stores `*.cpp` files in sub-directories. Particularly, I've tried the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26032630/2042546
I've also tried to manipulate the command itself `clang++ $< -o obj/$@` but it breaks whole idea of make and it's dependency management.

If I modify OBJ via `patsubstr` and `notdir`, make becomes unable to deduce dependency of a `*.o` on a corresponding `*.cpp` by it's path, cause `*.o`'s path loses it's directory part and becomes unable to find it's `*.cpp` file when executing `%.o:%.cpp` rule (I hope I managed to write down my thoughts correctly).

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you want the objects to be created as `obj/foo.o obj/bar.o obj/main.o` all in the same directory?  Or do you want them to be created as `obj/directory1/foo.o obj/directory2/bar.o obj/main.o`, so that the source file directory structure is preserved in the `obj` directory?

Comment: @MadScientist The latter (`obj/directory1/foo.o`) because it would correctly handle files with the same name. I guess I never though about it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want objects to live in the same source directory structure but under `obj`, then simply change your pattern rule (and how you generate the object files).  And you should create the directory first:

```
OBJ := $(SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
  ...
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        @echo "COMPILING SOURCE $< INTO OBJECT $@"
        @mkdir -p '$(@D)'
        @$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```